# Can I connect Sony HDR-AS100 to existing access point

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I would like to use the camera API to access the live view of a Sony HDR-AS100V camera. I also need my WIFI adaptor to connect to an existing access point. I cannot to the AP provided by the camera. 
Can I connect the camera to an external access point and access the API over this network connection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This functionality is not officially supported!!**
HDR-AS100V can connect to an external Wi-Fi access point and be controlled from your app using Camera Remote API over that connection.  But operation in this mode is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the positive answer. Is it documented how to do this? The user manual I downloaded only explains how to use the camera as access point.

Comment: Did you ever succeed in making this network configuration work ?

Comment: Prem, If you say this 'might' work and you are a member of the Sony team, can you please write 'how' this can happen and what needs to be done in order to activate this feature. I will do all the testing and no need for premisses, just the how's