# Camera Remote API network limitations

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Using the Smart Remote Control you can connect to the access point of the camera. Then using SSDP you can search for the Location

`# sudo tcpdump -vv -A -s 0 'port 1900 and host 239.255.255.250 and udp'`

LOCATION: http://192.168.122.1:64321/scalarwebapi_dd.xml

The XML files contains the action_list_url
                    http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony

So now you can run any API command (), but why not be able to just connect to your own access point and run the same process, is there a security limitation?

Testing with the cameras PlayMemories Camera Apps, you have to connect to an access point to access the internet (dhcp) and able to download new firmware to the camera and update the smart remote control.

So why not let the camera connect to an access point, using DHCP and then use SSPD to find the Location and control the camera with the standard API.

I see other posts asking similar questions:

[Sony Camera API and the Smart Remote Control app won't allow internet access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773245/sony-camera-api-and-the-smart-remote-control-app-wont-allow-internet-access)

[Sony Camera API Wifi, is it possible to connect the camera as a wifi client to an access point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013885/sony-camera-api-wifi-is-it-possible-to-connect-the-camera-as-a-wifi-client-to-a)

Are their plans to allow this in the future or is it limited due to security?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying out the camera remote API. Unfortunately there are no plans to allow different types of access to the camera API. For now you will have to connect to the camera's access point to use the API features. I don't have anything that I can share about why it works this way.

Comment: At least [one answer from Sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355031/can-i-connect-sony-hdr-as100-to-existing-access-point/24366604#24366604) suggests this access is possible (on certain models?) but didn't give any hints on how to enable it. If you know, can you give us a clue on accessing this undocumented feature?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the reply. For myself, I'm not concerned about connecting to multiple cameras, I'd just like to access the Camera Remote API on a single camera when the camera and my computer are both connected as clients to the same WLAN. The answer I linked makes it sound like that is possible: "HDR-AS100V can connect to an external Wi-Fi access point and be controlled from your app using Camera Remote API over that connection." Do you know how to enable that mode?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do understand what you are trying to do here. Again if this is possible we don't have a documented way of doing it and I can only imagine that it will produce less that great results if it does work. The camera remote API was just not designed to work this way. I do understand where you are coming from, but I have already talked with the camera team and we are just not able to assist with this particular set of functionality. I apologize for not being able to be of more help.