# Connect Android device to Sony Camera Remote API while simultaneously connected to internet

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I'm currently beginning to work on an Android application that can utilize the Sony Camera Remote API with the Sony DSC-QX10 camera. I've been looking at the sample application that comes with the Sony SDK and I'm trying to figure out how to connect my application to both the camera and some other API (e.g: Facebook) simultaneously.

Because I need to connect the Android device to the Camera's Access Point in order for the sample Android application to connect to the camera I don't see a way for my application to make the calls to another API without switching wi-fi networks in between taking a picture and sending the picture (which I really cannot do). I feel like this should certainly be possible and I'm just missing something. Is this possible or do I need to find a different SDK in order to have an application that takes pictures with an external camera that can simultaneously call other API's?

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found is to make a custom "smart" router using a Raspberry that give an access point to Android, connect to a wifi router for internet, and connect to the camera access point (3 wifi cards/keys required).

See there for details :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305264/9017111

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will only be able to access the Camera remote API while connected to it's wifi access point.